# Macro on variable initialization in c

Tags: c

Macro on variable initialization in C.

```
#define abcd

char abcd c[] = "AJITH";

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("%c",c[i]);
}
```

output:- `AJITH`

Why didn't compiler show an error? What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `#define` has no replacement text for `abcd`, any occurrence of `abcd` will basically be removed by the preprocessor, so

```
char abcd c[] = "AJITH";
```

becomes

```
char  c[] = "AJITH";
```

Answer (score 0):

`abcd` is expanded to blank.

so `char abcd c[] = "AJITH"` is expanded to `char c[] = "AJITH"`, which is perfectly fine.

Below is the output of your program only after preprocessing (gcc -E)

```
 char c[] = "AJITH";                                                            
 int i;                                                                         
 for(i=0;i<5;i++){                                                              
 printf("%c",c[i]);                                                             
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

```
#define abcd
```

there is no `macro-body` for `macro-name`. So it will replace `macro-name` with nothing.

After preprocessor stage your below code

```
#define abcd
int main(void) {
        char abcd c[] = "AJITH";
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                printf("%c",c[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

looks like this

```
int main(void) {
 char c[] = "AJITH";
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
  printf("%c",c[i]);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Hence it prints `AJITH`

*why didn't compiler shows the error?* This `#define abcd` is a empty string & empty define are allowed according to C standard.

From **C11 standard (n1570), § 6.10 Preprocessing directives**

> control-line:
>
> ```
> # define identifier replacement-list new-line
>    # define identifier lparen identifier-list(opt) ) replacement-list new-line
>    # define identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line
>    # define identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line
>
> replacement-list:
>     pp-tokens(opt)
> ```

As you can see above the `replacement-list:` and which is list of tokens & that can be empty.